# Extra conditions in composer controlled by atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents, atlas, conditional

I want to create a map series controlled by atlas, but some of my features have very different scales. I want to insert a condition to never use a scale lower than X (for instance: 1:5000). Any idea?

This is the result for one of the maps that zooms too much because it is shown just one point in the map.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Main Properties tab -> Scale -> Data Defined Override`, you need to write the following expression:

```
case 
when @map_scale < 5000 then 5000
else @map_scale
end
```

The above means that if the scale that fits the feature is less than `5000` then use the scale of `5000`, and if the scale that fits the feature is more than 5000 then use the best fit.

The above expression will prevent the scale to zoom in more than `5000`.

For example, I am using data from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) (UK Boundary) to test the above expression (but for this case I used a scale of `50,000`):

Without the above expression, the best fit for Bristol County is `39,688` as you can see below:

[image]

After applying the above expression with `50,000` instead of `5000` (as in your case), Bristol County zoomed out to `50,000` and it cannot be zoomed in less than the defined scale:

[image]