# Varying layout map scale based on layer visibility in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-print-layouts

I am looking for a method to vary the map scale of a QGIS layout according to the visibility of a layer.

The output should show the minimum scale at which the layer can be seen in the layout from a range of predefined scales (e.g. 1:1000, 1:2500 etc.).

I would like the method to work with the QGIS Atlas so that the output can be exported efficiently.

As an example, the images below show the layout at 1:1000 (site boundary only), 1:2500 (site boundary and surface water) and 1:5000 (site boundary and surface water). I would like the layout scale to automatically adjust depending on the minimum scale at which surface water can be seen from a range of predefined scales. So in this case, produce a layout at 1:2500 and not 1:1000 or 1:5000.

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253909/extra-conditions-in-composer-controlled-by-atlas?

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I am after. In the first instance the expression would need to be able to identify the visibility of the layer rather than the scale of the map.

Comment: Please provide additional details to your question like screenshot to make everything clear.

Comment: Please see update, hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: you could probably use a data-defined setting, with an expression based on the bounding box of the current atlas feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the distance to the closest surface water then use this distance to determine the appropriate scale.

- To calculate the distance to the closest water add a field (it doesn't seem to work with virtual field) in your
  site boundary layer and use :

  `geomnearest('SURFACE_WATER_LAYER_NAME','$distance')`

Then use this field to set the scale in your layout with an expression like this if you want to use a few scale:

```
CASE
WHEN "DISTANCE" < 500 THEN '1000'
WHEN "DISTANCE" > 5000 THEN '10000'
ELSE '5000'
END
```

where "DISTANCE" is your calculated field (adjust the numerical value to your need)

Or if you want something that give the biggest possible scale set the scale with :

```
"DISTANCE" / x
```

where "DISTANCE" is your calculated field and x is half of the shortest mesure of your map element en meter (so if you map element is 10 by 20 centimeter then x=0.05)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the surface water layer name is too large and returns an Eval Error: error: too many features to compare.

Comment: @RyanBell maybe you could simplify or use a subset of your surface water layer

Comment: I don't think simplify will help as the number of features will remain the same. I will explore splitting the data up.